# Asymptotic complexity of fixed-rank SVD

Tags: algorithms, complexity, svd

According to the W[ikipedia article on Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD), the asymptotic complexity of computing the SVD of an arbitrary m×n matrix M with m>n by the popular Householder QR methods is O(mn2). Are there any algorithms (perhaps Householder QR) that provide better asymptotic guarantees for fixed-rank matrices?

In other words: let Sn,k be the collection of n×n matrix of rank k. Are there algorithms that provide a better asymptotic complexity of computing the SVD of elements of Sn,k as n→∞ than O(n3)?

Comment: If you know the rank k, randomized SVD is extremely fast in practice (though asymptotically not better than rank revealing QR).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can run rank-revealing QR on your matrix $A$, which will stop at step $k$ (hence effectively terminating in $O(mnk)$) and produce $A = QRP$, where $R$ has nonzeros only in its first $k$ rows, and $Q,P$ are orthogonal. You can now compute and SVD of $R$, and use it to piece back the factors with a few matrix products with cost $O(\max(m,n)k^2)$.